# Can this glitch be reproduced?

Tags: canon, image-manipulation, canon-ixus

I used to own a Canon IXUS 400 that was glitchy.

Here's an example of a glitchy photo that it took:

[image]

This glitch [has been documented here](http://www.imaging-resource.com/badccds.html), and the manufacturers used to offer free repair of the products that would have the issue.

I am wondering if one would be able to reproduce this glitch, or a similar look, using software processing.

The effect described includes stretching of the image, an overlay of the image using different color maps, and a vertical dithering/interlacing of the data, as well as a general blue-ish tone with cyan and yellow and red spots.

Comment: Can you describe the glitch in the title of your question? It's useful if people can distinguish this question from questions about some *other* glitch without needing to see the example. (In search, for example.)

Comment: Various artists have reproduced glitches like this for their work, my immediate thought was the [album art for Nine Inch Nails' "With Teeth"](https://photos1.blogger.com/img/108/2928/640/Halo19.jpg), a technique he used again for his ["The Social Network" soundtrack CD](http://www.rob-sheridan.com/TSN/TSN07.jpg).  The Social Network blu-ray, I think, had an extra feature where he was describing how he, or the artist, did this for the album art.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve a similar effect in Photoshop using a combination of effects. Use the Puppet Warp (to distort your face and make it longer) and motion blur to blur it. I don't know how to tweak the colours though.

Good Luck

Greg

Comment: You could possibly get the colour effect by using Warp and motion blur on each channel independently